# Allow landscape orientation also to view controller pushed by uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am facing one issue regarding landscape orientation to view controller pushed by uiimagepickercontroller. I have written following code while pushing controller from picker.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
        UIImage *editImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        NSData *data=[[ConstantIM shareInstance] compressImage:editImage];

        self.imgCirclephoto.image = [ConstantIM  imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data] scaledToWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width scaledToHeight:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height];

        [[ConstantIM shareInstance] restrictRotation:NO];

        ImageChooseCancelView *cropController = [[ImageChooseCancelView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ImageChooseCancelView" bundle:nil];
        cropController.imgSel = editImage;
        cropController.imgDelegate = self;

        [picker pushViewController:cropController animated:YES];
}
```

In ImageChooseCancelView i have written following code to allow landscape mode:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cahnge the  interfaceOrienation mask .Try adding this in appDelegate

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
else  //iPad 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: @ShahPaneri your app is still crashing?

Comment: No. my app is not crashing but it's opening pushed view controller in landscape mode by imagepickercontroller. My image picker controller also not opening in landscape mode.